# Import XSD targetNameSpace From another Visual Studio project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, xsd, project-reference, config-designer-csd

I have a VB solution with many VB projects in it.  One of them, the "Core" project, has a `.xsd` file in it with a `targetNameSpace` of `urn:CustomNamespace`.

In the Core project, I am able to import the xsd namespace by doing the following:

```
Imports <xmlns="urn:CustomNamespace"/>
```

How can I get this `Imports` statement to work in a project that references the Core project?  In the Core, the xsd's namespace shows up with Intellisense.  This is not the case in the referring project.

I know this can be done somehow, as we are consuming a nuget package that has an xsd that we are importing.

******** **UPDATE** ********

It looks like the namespace Intellisense from the DLL in the nuget package is coming from a Configuration Section Designer xsd file, which is a `.csd.xsd` file. There are other related files to this, but I essentially want the same functionality that comes with referencing a package that has a `.csd.xsd` file.

It looks this is a VS add in located at https://csd.codeplex.com/.  I'll likely pull down the project to try to find out how they're doing it, but I'd appreciate an answer if someone knows how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Nuget is likely adding the schema file to the project referencing your "Core" project.  You can reference the same xsd file by adding it as a link to the referring project.

Right-click the (non-core) project, select Add>Existing item. Browse to the xsd file - and this bit is key - instead of clicking 'Add', click the little arrow next to "Add" and select "Add as link".

Comment: I don't want to do that if there's a way to import the xsd namespace without importing the xsd.  E.g., I can import `Core.Namespace` without having to do anything more than reference the project.  Is this how nuget packages achieve this?

Comment: Hmm. Try deleting the "Root namespace" in the project properties tab of the core module (if there is one). Then add a reference and try importing the namespace. You can try starting with `Global.` or use the Object Browser in the IDE (`F2` key)

Comment: It appears that you were correct, that I would need to link to the file in order to import the namespace from the xsd.  I updated your answer to reflect my situation-- the nuget package did in fact add the xsd directly to the project, which is why I was able to import that namespace.  I added a bounty, then found the file in my project-- I'll give you the bounty as soon as my waiting period is over.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the bounty. Happy programming! :-)